# How to configure orientdb for asynchronous replication

Tags: replication, distributed, orientdb

When using orientdb graph model, is there a global configuration to establish all db writes to be asynchronously replicated to other nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is in the file $ORIENTDB_HOME/config/default-distributed-db-config.json. This is the default content:

```
{
    "replication": true,
    "autoDeploy": true,
    "hotAlignment": true,
    "resyncEvery": 15,
    "clusters": {
        "internal": {
            "replication": false
        },
        "index": {
            "replication": false
        },
        "*": {
            "replication": true,
            "readQuorum": 1,
            "writeQuorum": 2,
            "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
            "readYourWrites": true,
            "partitioning": {
                "strategy": "round-robin",
                "default": 0,
                "partitions": [
                    [ "<NEW_NODE>" ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By default writeQuorum is 2. This means that it waits and checks the answer from at least 2 nodes before to send the ACK to the client. You could just set this to 1, so all the writes will be asynchronous.